# render двух yandex map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Не могу понять, почему рендерит две карты. При это, изменения вносятся на нижнюю карту, на верхнюю изменения не применяются.

component MapY:

```
import React from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, FullscreenControl, GeoObject } from "react-yandex-maps";

const mapData = {
center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
zoom: 5,
};

const MapY = () => {
 return (
    <YMaps>
        <div>
            <Map defaultState={mapData}>
                <FullscreenControl options={ { float: 'left' } }/>
                <GeoObject
                    geometry={ {
                        type: 'LineString',
                        coordinates: [
                            [55.76, 37.64],
                            [52.51, 13.38],
                        ],
                    } }
                    options={ {
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#F008',
                        strokeWidth: 6,
                    } }
                />
            </Map>

        </div>
    </YMaps>
);
};

export default MapY;
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import MapY from "./components/Map/MapY";


function App() {
  return (
     <MapY/>
);
}

export default App;
```

Выглядит это так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего у вас установлен React Strict Mode который изначально используется в "create-react-app" в новых версиях.
Проверьте обернуто ли App в  `<React.StrictMode>` в index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Strict Mode можно отключить просто удалив тэг `<React.StrictMode>`

```
root.render(
   <App />
);
```

StrictMode дважды рендерит компоненты (в dev, но не в production), чтобы обнаружить любые проблемы с вашим кодом.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/752005)

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало для меня

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте начать с одного файла, где все компоненты будут вместе. Если уже на этом этапе вы получаете такую же ошибку, значит проблема не в том куске что вы показали нам, потому что я почти что просто скопипастил ваш код и он работает как надо:

```js
const { YMaps, Map, FullscreenControl, GeoObject } = ReactYandexMaps;

const mapData = {
  center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
  zoom: 5,
};

const MapY = () => {
 return (
    <YMaps>
        <div>
            <Map defaultState={mapData}>
                <FullscreenControl options={ { float: 'left' } }/>
                <GeoObject
                    geometry={ {
                        type: 'LineString',
                        coordinates: [
                            [55.76, 37.64],
                            [52.51, 13.38],
                        ],
                    } }
                    options={ {
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#F008',
                        strokeWidth: 6,
                    } }
                />
            </Map>
        </div>
    </YMaps>
  );
};

function App() {
  return <MapY />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-yandex-maps/dist/production/react-yandex-maps.umd.js"></script>
```